# RecyclerView StateRestorationPolicy with combination of AppBarLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout

My layout is a set of RecyclerView and `AppBarLayout` on top of it. The `AppBarLayout`'s scrollFlags are: `scroll|enterAlways|snap`, so it's connected to the `RecyclerView`'s scrolling.
`RecyclerView` has `stateRestoration` of `RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY`, so it should return to its state, once user comes back.

The problem I'm having is that even though `stateRestoration` works fine, it restores *scrollPosition* as (*scrollPosition* minus  `AppBarLayout`'s height), which ultimately ruins the user experience `StateRestorationPolicy`'s bringing.

Is there any way to change this behaviour dynamically / or increment the *scrollPosition* of the `AppBarLayout` once user returns?